# Popper.js and flex-end causing body overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, popper.js

In my project, I have a list of dropdown buttons which are aligned right using `flex-end`. I've created a very minimal version of the code that shows the issue:

```js
var popper = new Popper(
  $('#anchor')[0],
  $('#popper')[0],
  {
    modifiers: {
      preventOverflow: {
        enabled: true,
        boundariesElement: 'window'
      }
    }
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.anchor {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  
  background-color: #333;
}
.popper {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  
  background-color: #c23;
  border: 2px solid #ae3;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 -6px;
}
li {
  margin: 0 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<ul class="parent">
  <li><div class="anchor"></div></li>
  <li><div class="anchor"></div></li>
  <li><div class="anchor"></div></li>
  <li>
    <div class="anchor" id="anchor"></div>
    <div class="popper" id="popper"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As seen above, the `.popper` div is overflowing `body`; causing a scrollbar to appear.

Removing the `li` makes Popper work as expected but I cannot do this as I'd lose my list. Using `flex-start` instead of `-end` also works correctly.

It's worth noting that the `.popper` and `.anchor` elements could be any width depending on what's in them.

Are there any workarounds or solutions for this behaviour? Preferably, without changing any markup.